# Linear Algebra problem about limits

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Thanks everyone for viewing my question! I'm getting stucked on this problem:
Suppose $A,B,C,D,E$ are real $n\times n$ matrices such that for any real number $t\neq 1,2$:
$$
I_n=(tI_n-A)(\frac{B}{(t-1)^3}+\frac{C}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{D}{t-1}+\frac{E}{t-2})
$$
The problem asks me to prove $C=(A-I)D=D(A-I)$.

**My progress:**

Multiply $t-1$ to both sides we obtain:
$$
(t-1)I_n=(tI_n-A)(\frac{B}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{C}{t-1}+D+\frac{(t-1)E}{t-2})
$$
Then take limits when $t\rightarrow 1$:
$$0=\lim_{t\rightarrow1}(I_n-A)(\frac{B}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{C}{t-1}+D) \\(A-I_n)D=\lim_{t\rightarrow1}(I_n-A)(\frac{B}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{C}{t-1})
$$
This is really close to the required form but I do not know how to continue, I saw some answer concluding that:
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow1}(I_n-A)(\frac{B}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{C}{t-1})=C
$$
I don't know if this is correct and it makes no sense to me.
Thanks so much for your answers in advance!

Comment: I would first change variables by letting $r=t-1$ (because I think it may be easier), then multiply through by $r^3(r-1)$ and equate terms on either side that have the same exponent on $r$ (although I'm not sure the rigorous justification for that). I don't see how that's going to show that $D$ commutes with $A$ though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $s=t-1$ and $A'=A-I$. Then
\begin{align}
I&=(sI-A')\left(\frac{B}{s^3}+\frac{C}{s^2}+\frac{D}{s}+\frac{E}{s-1}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=-\frac{A'B}{s^3}+\frac{B-A'C}{s^2}+\frac{C-A'D}{s}+D-\frac{(sI-A')E}{s-1}.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d^2}{ds^2}(s^3I)
=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\left(-A'B+s(B-A'C)+s^2(C-A'D)+s^3D-\frac{s^3(sI-A')E}{s-1}\right)
$$
and $C=A'D$. Since $(1)$ also implies that
$$
I=\left(\frac{B}{s^3}+\frac{C}{s^2}+\frac{D}{s}+\frac{E}{s-1}\right)(sI-A'),
$$
we also obtain $C=DA'$ by a similar argument.

Comment: Oh, so the rigorous justification is because it's a differentiable function of $s$, so you can differentiate as many times as needed, then set $s=0$. Also, they commute because they are inverses. Nice. +1